# Unable to replace characters in a String

Tags: java

I am trying to go through an array of characters and replace that character in the string with the parallel character in the other array.

```
private String replace(String input)
{
    char[] first = {'a','e','o','s'};
    char[] second = {'@','3','0','$'};
    String myCopy = input.toLowerCase();


    for(int y = 0; y < first.length; y++)
    {
        myCopy.replace(first[y],second[y]);
    }


    return myCopy;
}
```

Here's and example of what I get:

```
Enter a string: as the dog runs here
Output: as the dog runs here
```

It always outputs the same string with no replacements.

I also tried using:

```
myCopy.replace('a','@');

and

myCopy.replace("a","@");
```

and the replaceAll method.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Java. `replace()` doesn't *change* the string you call it on - it *returns* a new string with the changes. So you want:

```
myCopy = myCopy.replace(first[y], second[y]);
```

(The same is true for *all* the methods on `String` which "appear" to be changing it, as it's immutable.)

Answer (score 5):

String.replace() will return a new string. Strings are immutable in java.

What you are looking for is probably [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). You can build it from string, change it as long as you need and then generate an immutable String as a result via [toSting()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString%28%29).

Comment: Thank you so much.  So simple I never even realized it.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable. So in your for loop your operation is not having any tangible effect. You need to assign the result of `replace` back to the original variable:

```
for(int y = 0; y < first.length; y++) {
    myCopy = myCopy.replace(first[y],second[y]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is not working is that you are not assigning the returned String value to the array.  This:

```
     for(int y = 0; y < first.length; y++)   
  {     
    myCopy.replace(first[y],second[y]); 
    }
```

Needs to become:

```
 for(int y = 0; y < first.length; y++)   
  {     
    myCopy =  myCopy.replace(first[y],second[y]); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confused with `String` and `replace()`. String is *immutable*, i.e. you cannot change its state. Calling `replace()` creates copy of source string and returns it. Do something like this:

`String replacedString = myCopy.replace(first[y],second[y]);`

Answer (score 0):

As Michal said, Strings are immutable.  If this is being used in a process that is more intensive, you may want to use StringBuffer instead.  StringBuffer is mutable, however it will take some additional work as it doesn't have a directly comparable `replace()` method.