# how do I to replace a detected String in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to parse some extracted data. So, I can't find how do I to replace a detected String in Java?

I've tried this, but it doesn't work for me :

```
texte.replace("gras", "bold");
```

Any help please ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to replace characters in a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772883/unable-to-replace-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable. You need to assign the returned string to a string variable. E.g.

```
texte = texte.replace("gras", "bold");
```

or

```
String replaced = texte.replace("gras", "bold");
```

Answer (score 0):

strings are immutable assign result back to texte

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, calling a method on a string will never change it.

```
texte = texte.replace("gras", "bold");
```

should do the trick